# Why do all my git refspecs have the "optional +" in them, seemingly by default?

Tags: git

[This page on git refspecs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec) and [this section of the git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt-ltrefspecgt82308203) both suggest that git refspecs do *not* have a '+' in front of them by default. But all the refspecs in my git repos do have that + in front of them, apparently by default. (I definitely did not put them there manually.)

Why might that be?

The configuration in my global .gitconfig file is:

```
[push]
    default = current
[core]
    excludesfile = ~/.gitignore
```

Edit: Thank you, everyone, for the clarifying questions.

I've added additional remotes to a bunch of my git repos using `git add remote`. In the config file for the repo the "fetch" refspecs for the additional remote branches have the "+" in front of them. (As torek said, the refspec for `origin` also has the "+.")

Here's one example of a `.git/config` file. I've looked up the documentation for all the settings in the `[core]` section, but it doesn't seem like any of that is affecting the refspecs.

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/[my fork of a github repo]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "main"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/main
[remote "partner"]
    url = https://github.com/[a different fork of the repo]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/partner/*
[remote "upstream"]
    url = https://github.com/[the original repo I forked from]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*
```

Comment: Where do you see these "+" displayed? `git branch` output?

Comment: Please show the command you are running, and the output you are seeing.

Comment: The standard `remote.origin.fetch` setting, which is the first refspec most will encounter, is `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`. This refspec means that your `git fetch origin` will force-update all your remote-tracking branches in `refs/remotes/origin/*`. But you say *all* your refspecs, hence the questions above my comment...

Comment: Thank you for the clarifying questions, everyone. I've edited my original post to try to address them.